# Django Admin customization

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to add a link in admin panel of my "Model EVENT" that will redirect me to a new page , from where admin can send email to registered user.
I have tried it by adding change_form.html in templates/admin/app/change_form.html then it's working but the problem is that the link which i want to show in model Event is also showing in other models of that app and when i want to add objects in any model of the app, it is throwing an error of no reverse match.
Help me to add the link in admin panel of Event model only. Thanks in advance

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import date
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.conf import settings

class Venue(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Venue Name', max_length=120)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    zip_code = models.CharField('Zip/Post Code', max_length=12,blank=True, null=True)

    VENUE_STATUS = (
        ('on', 'Online'),
        ('os', 'Onsite'),
        )
    venue_status_label = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=VENUE_STATUS,
        default='os',
        help_text='Choose Venue either ONLINE or ONSITE',
        )


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def check_status_venue(self):
        if self.venue_status_label == 'on':
            print("Trueeee")
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class RegisteredUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['user']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Organizer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Organizer Name', max_length=120)
    phone = models.CharField('Contact Phone', max_length=20)
    email_address = models.EmailField('Organizer Email')
    website = models.URLField('Web Address',blank=True, null=True)
    organizer_picture = models.ImageField(help_text="Add image of organizer")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Add category of event")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category_title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_title


class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length=120)
    day = models.DateField("Day of Event",default=now)
    start_time = models.TimeField("Starting Time",default=now)
    end_time = models.TimeField("Ending Time",default=now)
    picture = models.ImageField(help_text="Add picture related to event")
    description = models.TextField('Event Description')
    featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    cost = models.IntegerField(help_text="Add cost of event in case of free, write 0")
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    event_manager = models.ManyToManyField(Organizer,blank =False)
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    EVENT_STATUS = (
        ('o', 'On Time'),
        ('d', 'Delayed'),
        ('c', 'Completed'),
        )

    Event_Show = (
        ('e', 'Enable Event'),
        ('d', 'Disable Event'),
    )

    label = models.CharField(
        max_length=1,
        choices=EVENT_STATUS,
        default='o',
        help_text='Choose Event Status from here',
        )
    Event_Show_Status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=Event_Show,default='e',help_text='Either ENABLE and DISABLE your event')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Events:startup-event-detail', kwargs = {'slug':self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-day']

    def clean(self):
        if self.end_time <= self.start_time:
            raise ValidationError('Ending times must after starting times')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'day', 'venue', 'label')
    list_filter = ('day', 'label', 'featured','Event_Show_Status','venue__venue_status_label',)
    search_fields = ['name','day', 'cost', 'categories__category_title', 'event_manager__name','venue__venue_status_label'] #incomplete searc using venue
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        print("urlsss",urls)

        my_urls = [
            path('<int:event_id>/send_email/', self.send_email, name='send_email'),
        ]

        return my_urls + urls

    def send_email(self, request,event_id ):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            header = admin.site.site_header
            event_id = event_id
            event = get_object_or_404(Event , pk = event_id)
            list_of_attendess = event.attendees.all()
            form = WebinarMailForm()
            message = ''
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = WebinarMailForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    subject = form.cleaned_data['Subject']
                    content = form.cleaned_data['Content']
                    event = get_object_or_404(Event , pk = event_id)
                    name = request.user.pk
                    list_of_attendess = event.attendees.all()
                    emails = []
                    for user in list_of_attendess:
                        emails.append(user.email)
                    try:
                        message = "Sent Successfully"
                        send_mail(subject,content,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,emails,fail_silently=False)
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return render(request,'admin/send_email.html', {'form':form,'event_id':event_id,'total_attendees':len(list_of_attendess),'header':header,'message':message} )
        else:
            raise Http404("Only admin can view this page")
```

templates/admin/sent_email.html

```
{% extends "admin/app_index.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Webinar Email' %}{% endblock %}
{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans header %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<fieldset class="module aligned wide extrapretty">
    <h2>Email Webinar link to Attendees <a href="{% url 'admin:Events_event_changelist' %}" style="color:white">Event List</a>
    <a href="{% url 'admin:Events_event_change' object_id=event_id %}" style="color:white"> Back</a> </h2> 
    </fieldset>
<h3>Total Attendees: {{total_attendees}}</h3>
<form action="{% url 'admin:send_email' event_id=event_id %}" method='post'>  
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{field.label_tag}}
        {{field.errors}}
        {{field}}

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="send mail">
</form>
{{message}}

{% endblock %}
```

templates/admin/Events(app)/change_form.html

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}
{% block form_top %}
{% comment %} id of list view original is builtin {{ original.pk }} {% endcomment %}
<fieldset class="module aligned wide extrapretty">
    <h2>Send Webinar attending link to attendees</h2>
    </fieldset>
  <a href="{% url 'admin:send_email' event_id=original.pk %}"> Send Email for Webinar </a>
  <fieldset class="module aligned wide extrapretty">
    <h2>Event Information</h2>
    </fieldset>
{% endblock %}
```

link http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/Events/event/2/send_email/ which redirects me on send_email page and working perfect but i want to place it in admin panel in my Event model only.

Comment: Isn't it better to add that `send email` button as an action?

Comment: How can i add it as an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `send_mail` as an action; this way, there you need a very *little* change in your `ModelAdmin` and you can also select **multiple** `Events` to send mail for them.

This is basically how you should implement it:

```
@admin.register(Event)
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'day', 'venue', 'label')
    list_filter = ('day', 'label', 'featured','Event_Show_Status','venue__venue_status_label',)
    search_fields = ['name','day', 'cost', 'categories__category_title', 'event_manager__name','venue__venue_status_label'] #incomplete searc using venue

    actions = ['send_mail']

    def send_email(self, request, queryset):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            header = admin.site.site_header
            event_ids = queryset.values_list('pk', flat=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/send_email/ids=%s' % (
                ','.join(str(pk) for pk in event_ids),
            ))
```

Then, add a `url` like `path('send_email/', views.send_mail_view)` and move *all* your logics for sending email there.

Read more about actions in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/)

Comment: Thanks alot for this solution it solved my problem. Please correct few things actions = ['send_email'] and path('send_email/', views.send_mail_view)

Comment: Glad to help. I fix those issues, thanks (btw, you can suggest edit on the answer).